# Is that the only way to start a hadoop job from command line?

Tags: hadoop

I work on hadoop now, in Pseudo-distributed mode.
I try some mapreduce,package it as jar,and copy the file to hadoop.then use

***./bin/hadoop jar ******

to start it.

My question is:Is there any **other way** to do it?If we have thousands of jobs to run.We can't just type in command.What we do in the PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT?

thanks.

Comment: normally,we write some jobs in shell script.just like: jobs.sh :bin/hadoop jar a.jar \r\n bin/hadoop jar b.jar,and they are running one by one in FIFO order.that's a batch job. if u want Running jobs parallely in hadoop, try  Fair Scheduler or Capacity Scheduler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 1000s of jobs, write a shell script and submit them if there are no dependencies between the jobs. If there are dependencies then use try using Apache Oozie as Chris mentioned.

Comment: write a shell script,is that you mean like this:    ./bin/hadoop jar a.jar com.A   ./bin/hadoop jar b.jar com.B  ,i did not try it. but i guess it will block.

Comment: can u give some example that what the shell script like in a PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT?

Comment: What will block? You can schedule any number of jobs theoretically and the scheduler in Hadoop will schedule them appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible launch MapReduce jobs in an automated way.  For example, a java program, you can launch a job.  the trick is to ensure that you export your Job into a jar file, and call that exported jar file from your java code (which is separate).  I had a similar question recently and posted it and perhaps it relates to you as well.

[Launch a mapreduce job from eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236305/launch-a-mapreduce-job-from-eclipse)

Comment: i read that,i guess that u want do a remote debug?if u mean that,try Java Platform Debugger Architecture(JPDA)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to schedule jobs to run, or want to design a workflow of jobs with inter-dependencies then look into Apache OOZIE.